# How to pop up a new window with the same URL + query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Current window

```
http://www.testing.com/default.aspx
```

or

```
http://www.testing.com/default.aspx?id=1
```

Pop Up Window

```
http://www.testing.com/default.aspx?p=1
```

or

```
http://www.testing.com/default.aspx?id=1&p=1
```

What I have is

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="window.open(document.location.href + '?&p=1')">
 Print Page   
</a>
```

which is a bit wrong as pop up will become

```
http://www.testing.com/default.aspx?id=1?&p=1
```

i just need a tweak.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this a few ways... This is how I would make it work:

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="window.open(document.location.href + (document.location.href.indexOf('?') >= 0 ?  '&p=1' : '?p=1'))">
 Print Page   
</a>
```

**EDIT:** Updated to put querystring appending in parentheses.

Comment: ?id=1 is gone after adding in &p=1

Comment: May need to make sure that portion of the code is wrapped in parentheses, I updated my answer accordingly.